# Hide elements based on value in asp.net?

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc

I have a drop-down list with 2 values in a form in a ASP.NET MVC 5 Razor View .Based on the values of the drop down list I want to show and hide elements in the form.I used Bootstrap 3.4.1 class "hidden" to hide the elements and jquery function $("#Name").show() to show the elements.The issue is that the elements are always hidden,doesn't matter what is the value of the dropdownlist.This is the jquery code:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
            console.log("sss")
            $('#IndividualType').on('change', function () {            
                if (this.value == '0') {
                    $("#Name").show();
                } else {
                    $("#Name").hide();
                }
            }).trigger("change");
        });
```

And this is the ASP.NET code:

```
 <div class="form-group hidden">

            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })

        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
const val = 1; /* assuming you will get value to compare */
$(function() {
  $('#colorselector').change(function() {
    if (val === 1) { /* your condition which will prompt for true/false */
      alert("value found");
      $('.colors').hide();
      $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
    } else {
      alert("value Not found");
      $('.colors').show();
      $('#' + $(this).val()).hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<Select id="colorselector">
  <option value="red">Red</option>
  <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
</Select>
<div id="red" class="colors" style="display:none"> red... </div>
<div id="yellow" class="colors" style="display:none"> yellow.. </div>
<div id="blue" class="colors" style="display:none"> blue.. </div>
```